# How do you change the preview limit in a CKAN Dataset?

Tags: ckan

When viewing the preview data of a CSV the record limit is set by default at 1000, i can't find where do this parameter is set, is it possible to redifine it's value? if so, where is set?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether I have understood your question correctly and I am not sure which backend you are using but I assume that you could add

```
dataset.size = 2000;
```

to the first line of the function `initializeDataExplorer` in the `preview_recline.js` file (https://github.com/okfn/ckan/blob/master/ckanext/reclinepreview/theme/public/preview_recline.js#L104).

Answer (score 0):

You must edit these files:

- /ckan/ckanext/reclinepreview/theme/public/vendor/recline/recline.js
- /ckan/ckanext/reclinepreview/theme/public/vendor/recline/recline.min.js

In the recline.js, in the line 470, you can change the limit of 1000 lines:

```
  my.fetch = function(dataset) {
    var data = {
      url: dataset.url,
      'max-results':  dataset.size || dataset.rows || 1000,
      type: dataset.format || ''
    };
```

I changed 1000 to 2000.

```
  my.fetch = function(dataset) {
    var data = {
      url: dataset.url,
      'max-results':  dataset.size || dataset.rows || 2000,
      type: dataset.format || ''
    };
```

Remember do the same change in recline.min.js